# d3 Create an area chart with missing data point and defined() doesn't work

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am creating an area chart with d3 (maybe v4). In the database, it has some data points doesn't have the key I want. I mean it has missing data, which cause I can't create an area chart with the all data.

I already tried to use following code to remove the data point with missing data, but it doesn't work:

```
drawAirVisualData(data) {

    var divE = document.createElement("div");
    var divId = document.createAttribute('id');
    divId.value = 'AirVisualDiv';
    divE.setAttributeNode(divId);
    divE.style.textAlign = "center";
    var title = document.createElement("text");
    title.style.lineHeight = "40px";
    title.style.fontSize = "20px";
    title.textContent = "Air Visual";

    document.getElementById('chartDiv').appendChild(divE);
    document.getElementById('AirVisualDiv').appendChild(title);

    // for each chart, the x and xAxis are same, the y and yAxis are always changed.

  var width = w - margin.left - margin.right,
        height = (h - margin.top) / 9;

  var parseTime = d3.time.format.utc("%H:%M").parse,
    midnight = parseTime("00:00");

  var x = d3.time.scale.utc()
      .domain([midnight, d3.time.day.utc.offset(midnight,1)])
      .range([0, width]);

  var xAxis =  d3.svg.axis().scale(x)
    .orient("bottom").ticks(25).tickFormat(d3.time.format.utc("%I %p"));

    //---------------------------- chart 1-------------------------------
    var y = d3.scale.linear()
        .range([height, 0])
        .domain([0, 100]);
    var yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(y)
        .orient("left").ticks(10);


    var areaInHumidity = d3.svg.area()
      .defined(function (d) {
        return d.y1 != null;
      })
        .x(function (d) {
          var time = new Date(d.created_at);
          return x(time);
        })
        .y0(height)
        .y1(function (d, i) {
            var humidity = d.data["current"].hm;
            return y(humidity);
        });

    var areaOutHumidity = d3.svg.area()
      .defined(function (d) {
        return d.y1 != null;
      })
      .x(function (d) {
         var time = new Date(d.created_at);
         var dayTime = time.getHours() + time.getMinutes() / 60 + time.getSeconds() / 3600;
         return x(dayTime);
        })
        .y0(height)
        .y1(function (d) {
            var humidity = d.data.outdoor_weather.hu;
            return y(humidity);
        });

    var chart1 = d3.select("#AirVisualDiv")
        .append("svg")
        .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
        .append("g")
        .attr('id', 'HumidityChart')
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

    // Add legend
    chart1.append('text').text('Outdoor Humidity - Indoor Humidity').attr("x", width / 2).attr("y", 0).attr("text-anchor", "middle");
    chart1.append("circle").attr("cx", width * 7 / 10).attr("cy", 10).attr("r", 6)
        .style({
            'fill': "#0d7dfa",
            'opacity': 0.2
        });
    chart1.append("circle").attr("cx", width * 8 / 10).attr("cy", 10).attr("r", 6)
        .style({
            'fill': "#0d7dfa",
            'opacity': 0.6
        });
    chart1.append("text").attr("x", (width * 7 / 10) + 14).attr("y", 10).text("Indoor Humidity").style("font-size", "12px").attr("alignment-baseline", "middle");
    chart1.append("text").attr("x", (width * 8 / 10) + 14).attr("y", 10).text("Outdoor Humidity").style("font-size", "12px").attr("alignment-baseline", "middle");



  chart1.append("g")
    .attr("class", "axisLine")
    .style("font", "12px centralesanscndlight")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(xAxis);


  // Add the X Axis
    chart1.append("g")
        .style("font", "12px centralesanscndlight")
        .style('stroke-width', 1)
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
        .call(xAxis);

    // Add the Y Axis
    chart1.append("g")
        .attr("class", "axisLine")
        .style("font", "12px centralesanscndlight")
        .call(yAxis);

    // Add area for indoor humidity
    chart1.append('path')
        .attr({
            'd': areaInHumidity(data),
            'fill': '#0d7dfa',
            'opacity': 0.2
        });

    // Add area for outdoor humidity
    chart1.append('path')
        .attr({
            'd': areaOutHumidity(data),
            'fill': '#0d7dfa',
            'opacity': 0.6
        });

    //---------------------------- chart 2-------------------------------
    var y2 = d3.scale.linear()
        .range([height, 0])
        .domain([0, 50]);
    var yAxis2 = d3.svg.axis().scale(y2)
        .orient("left").ticks(10);

    var areaInTemp = d3.svg.area()
      .defined(function (d) {
        return d.y != null;
      })
        .x(function (d) {
            var time = new Date(d.created_at);
            var dayTime = time.getHours() + time.getMinutes() / 60 + time.getSeconds() / 3600;
            return x(dayTime);
        })
        .y0(height)
        .y1(function (d) {
            var temperature = d.data.current.tp;
            return y2(temperature);
        });

    var areaOutTemp = d3.svg.area()
      .defined(function (d) {
        return d.y != null;
      })
        .x(function (d) {
            var time = new Date(d.created_at);
            var dayTime = time.getHours() + time.getMinutes() / 60 + time.getSeconds() / 3600;
            return x(dayTime);
        })
        .y0(height)
        .y1(function (d) {
            var temperature = d.data.outdoor_weather.tp;
            return y2(temperature);
        });

    var chart2 = d3.select("#AirVisualDiv")
        .append("svg")
        .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

    chart2.append('text').text('Outdoor Temperature - Indoor Temperature').attr("x", width / 2).attr("y", 0).attr("text-anchor", "middle");

    // Add legend
    chart2.append("circle").attr("cx", width * 7 / 10).attr("cy", 10).attr("r", 6)
        .style({
            'fill': "#f26100"
        });
    chart2.append("circle").attr("cx", width * 8 / 10).attr("cy", 10).attr("r", 6)
        .style({
            'fill': "#ff9b00"
        });
    chart2.append("text").attr("x", (width * 7 / 10) + 14).attr("y", 10).text("Indoor Temperature").style("font-size", "12px").attr("alignment-baseline", "middle");
    chart2.append("text").attr("x", (width * 8 / 10) + 14).attr("y", 10).text("Outdoor Temperature").style("font-size", "12px").attr("alignment-baseline", "middle");

    // Add the X Axis
    chart2.append("g")
        .attr("class", "axisLine")
        .style("font", "12px centralesanscndlight")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
        .call(xAxis);

    // Add the Y Axis
    chart2.append("g")
        .attr("class", "axisLine")
        .style("font", "12px centralesanscndlight")
        .call(yAxis2);

    // Add area for indoor humidity
    chart2.append('path')
        .attr({
            'd': areaInTemp(data),
            'fill': orange,
            'opacity': 0.5
        });

    // Add area for outdoor humidity
    chart2.append('path')
        .attr({
            'd': areaOutTemp(data),
            'fill': lightorange,
            'opacity': 0.5
        });

    //---------------------------- chart 3-------------------------------
    var y3 = d3.scale.linear()
        .range([height, 0])
        .domain([0, 1000]);
    var yAxis3 = d3.svg.axis().scale(y3)
        .orient("left").ticks(10);

    var coLine = d3.svg.line()
      .defined(function (d) {
        return d.y != null;
      })
        .x(function (d) {
            var time = new Date(d.created_at);
            var dayTime = time.getHours() + time.getMinutes() / 60 + time.getSeconds() / 3600;
            return x(dayTime);
        })
        .y(function (d) {
            var co = d.data.current.co;
            return y3(co);
        });

    var chart3 = d3.select("#AirVisualDiv")
        .append("svg")
        .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

    chart3.append('text').text('CO2 Level').attr("x", width / 2).attr("y", 0).attr("text-anchor", "middle");

    // Add the X Axis
    chart3.append("g")
        .attr("class", "axisLine")
        .style("font", "12px centralesanscndlight")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
        .call(xAxis);

    // Add the Y Axis
    chart3.append("g")
        .attr("class", "axisLine")
        .style("font", "12px centralesanscndlight")
        .call(yAxis3);

    // Add line for co2
    chart3.append('path')
        .attr({
            'd': coLine(data),
            'stroke': grey,
            'stroke-width': '1.5px',
            'fill': 'none'
        });

    //---------------------------- chart 4-------------------------------
    var y4 = d3.scale.linear()
        .range([height, 0])
        .domain([0, 50]);
    var yAxis4 = d3.svg.axis().scale(y4)
        .orient("left").ticks(10);

    var p2Line = d3.svg.line()
      .defined(function (d) {
        return d.y != null;
      })
        .x(function (d) {
            var time = new Date(d.created_at);
            var dayTime = time.getHours() + time.getMinutes() / 60 + time.getSeconds() / 3600;
            return x(dayTime);
        })
        .y(function (d) {
            var p2 = d.data.current.p2;
            return y4(p2);
        });

    var chart4 = d3.select("#AirVisualDiv")
        .append("svg")
        .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

    chart4.append('text').text('PM 2.5 Level').attr("x", width / 2).attr("y", 0).attr("text-anchor", "middle");

    // Add the X Axis
    chart4.append("g")
        .attr("class", "axisLine")
        .style("font", "12px centralesanscndlight")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
        .call(xAxis);

    // Add the Y Axis
    chart4.append("g")
        .attr("class", "axisLine")
        .style("font", "12px centralesanscndlight")
        .call(yAxis4);

    // Add line for co2
    chart4.append('path')
        .attr({
            'd': p2Line(data),
            'stroke': grey,
            'stroke-width': '1.5px',
            'fill': 'none'
        });
}
```

The normal data point looks like:

```
{clusterAliases: ["dlab"]
created_at: "2019-06-04T05:15:18.794Z"
data:{
 current:{
    co: 429,
    hm: 62,
    p01: 17,
    p1: 25,
    p2: 22,
    tp: 22.7834,
    ts: "2019-06-04T05:10:10.646Z",
    __proto__: Object},
outdoor_station: {
    p1: {…}, 
    api_id: 1646, 
    ts: "2019-06-04T04:00:00.000Z", 
    p2: {…}, 
    mainus: "p2"},
outdoor_weather: {
    wd: 0, 
    hu: 40, 
    ic: "01d", 
    ts: "2019-06-04T05:00:00.000Z", 
    tp: 33,
    __proto__: Object},
identifier: "54:C9:DF:E3:AE:19",
meta: {version: 0},
type: "AQI_STATUS",
updated_at: "2019-06-04T05:15:18.808Z",
__v: 1,
_id: "5cf5fe661d9b1900213c98ec",
__proto__: Object}
```

The missing data point looks like:

```
{clusterAliases: ["dlab"]
created_at: "2019-06-04T05:13:50.977Z"
data:{
    message: "HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.airvisual.com', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=10)"
    status: "ERROR",
    __proto__: Object
    },
identifier: "54:C9:DF:E3:AE:19",
meta: {version: 0},
type: "ERROR",
updated_at: "2019-06-04T05:13:50.990Z",
__v: 1,
_id: "5cf5fe0e1d9b1900213c98e5",
__proto__: Object}
```

The big difference between normal data point and missing data point is in missing data point it does't have "current" key under data, and its type shows "ERROR". I already tried to remove this data point before it was used to create area chart, but it can't be removed. so I also tried to use `defined()` to overcome it, but it doesn't work. Does anyone know how to overcome or remove the missing data point from area chart by d3? Thank you.

Comment: This is d3v3 or earlier. Also, you do not have a `y` property in any of your data items, why are you using `d.y`? If you post a snippet of your code (with a few lines of data) it will be easier to point out a solution.

Comment: I want to ignore the data point that doesn't have this key("current ")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"I checked the d3 API and noticed that '''defined()''' required to have at least the key of the value. for example,"
'''
data {
  temperature: 65,
  humidity: null
}
'''
"this kind of data missing can be solved by" ''' defined()'''
"However, when the key (in our case humidity) is missing, '''defined()''' can not overcome the missing data anymore. to solve this problem, my current solution is to check if it has a key, if not, then define a value for y/x to keep drawing the line or areas"